# OS X: how to figure out what prevents L2TP/IPSec from running correctly

Tags: macos, sockets, ports, ipsec, l2tp

It seems that an old installation of Cisco Anyconnect prevents the OS X built-in L2TP/IPSec client from running (I posted a question here: [OS X 10.7, can't log into any L2TP VPN server](https://superuser.com/questions/379159/os-x-10-7-cant-log-into-any-l2tp-vpn-server), but didn't get any results).

What is the best way to figure out if anything is taking over the sockets or ports required for L2TP/Ipsec? I tried some basic netstat and lsof and couldn't see anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It wasn't ports and sockets. Turns out that something (possibly CiscoAnyconnect) has unloaded racoon on startup. To fix (with Anyconnect uninstalled) do the following:

`launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.racoon.plist`

You may also start racoon manually by:

`sudo /usr/sbin/racoon`