# OSX: how to check what is taking ports or sockets

Tags: macos, osx-lion, sockets, ports

I am having trouble with L2TP/IPSec on my OS X 10.7.2 machine and I was wondering what is the best way to figure out which process is taking particular sockets or ports;

My related posts (below), were more particular, but I couldn't figure it out. I am asking more general question, hopefully there would be someone who could help.
[OS X: how to figure out what prevents L2TP/IPSec from running correctly](https://superuser.com/questions/379913/os-x-how-to-figure-out-what-prevents-l2tp-ipsec-from-running-correctly)
and
[OS X 10.7, can't log into any L2TP VPN server](https://superuser.com/questions/379159/os-x-10-7-cant-log-into-any-l2tp-vpn-server)

Edit: I tried netstat and lsof but didn't see anything related to my problem. Also it isn't the router (other machines behind it work fine); it is not the firewall (same issue with it off) or LittleSnitch (same issue with it off).
There was CiscoANyconnect installed, but the issue persists even after uninstall. My hypothesis is that it changed something that persists even after uninstall.

Comment: `lsof -i -P` doesn't show anything useful either?

Comment: Nothing in lsof or netstat.

Comment: How do you know the socket and/or port begin used is the problem? Does restarting the machine help?

Comment: I don't and restarting doesn't help (even installing 10.7. on top of 10.6 didn't help). I don't want to do clean install, but that may be the only option. When starting the built-in VPN client, it says the following in ppp.log and system.log: `timestamp : L2TP: cannot connect racoon control socket: No such file or directory`. Because of that I thought that it could be socket or port. But it could be something completely different. Also, LittleSnitch doesn't show any attempt for connection to anything outside (the VPN server).

Comment: Just caught the edit, ignore the answer. I've seen cisco anyconnect mess up quite a few macs lately. even after you uninstall it.

Comment: Would it be feasible for you to simply reinstall the system, restoring your settings, programs, and personal files from Time Machine? I've done this a few times (including when a third party driver caused crashes during system start) and it's usually successful.

Comment: @skub: Yes, that's why my guess was that Cisco Anyconnect did that; the log entry is about racoon that seems to be IPSec related and Anyconnect uses IPSec

Comment: @Daniel Beck: I have too many customizations on this machine. But that would be the last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. It wasn't ports and sockets. Turns out that something (possibly CiscoAnyconnect) has unloaded racoon on startup. To fix (with Anyconnect uninstalled) do the following:

`launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.racoon.plist`

You may also start racoon manually by:

`sudo /usr/sbin/racoon`